# Trouble definining a function to use only certain heads

Tags: functions

I'm trying to write a function that accepts only a particular Head (for example, prints only Symbols) using pattern matching. However, the following code has me a bit of confused.

```
> printer[foo_] := Print[foo]
> printer[1]
1
```

This behaviour makes sense: the `_` matches the Integer (`1`) and the printer works. Now I redefine the `printer` function:

```
> printer[foo_Symbol] := Print[foo]
> printer[1]
1
```

Now `_Symbol` should *not* match an Integer and I would expect `printer[1]` to be returned.

To make matters worse, if I'd done this in the opposite order, first defining `printer[var_Symbol]` then changing the definition to `printer[var_]`, I get the expected result.

What's going on?

(Mathematica 10.0.1.0 on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Well, you have both definitions in context, and both definitions combine to mean, print anything, hence, the result you get. You'll have to clear `printer` first then redefine the second one only to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Look at the result of `??foo`. That will show you all the all the rules that are in force for evaluating `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on is pretty simple: *Mathematica* does not forget your first definition because the pattern is different. This makes sense! Assume you define the faculty

```
fac[0] = 1;
fac[n_] := fac[n - 1]*n
```

and your second definition line would overwrite the first one. Then, nothing would work because you would have killed the end of the recursion.

Your second part

> To make matters worse, if I'd done this in the opposite order, first defining printer[var_Symbol] then changing the definition to printer[var_], I get the expected result.

is not true if you really did what you wrote. Let's define it the other way around:

```
ClearAll[printer]    
printer[foo_Symbol] := Print[foo]
printer[foo_] := Print[foo]

printer[1]
(* 1 *)
```

Here, too, the `1` is printed. This makes perfect sense because when you look at the rule attached to `printer`

```
DownValues[printer]
(* {HoldPattern[printer[foo_Symbol]] :> Print[foo], 
 HoldPattern[printer[foo_]] :> Print[foo]} *)
```

you see that both definitions are there. Since the first one with `foo_Symbol` doesn't match, *Mathematica* tries the next one which matches.

So if you want to make that `printer[1]` stays unevaluated, you cannot define a general rule which matches. Clear all definitions of printer and use the `foo_Symbol` definition only.